# How are proto files shared among relevant microservices?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I am building a microservice application adopting gRPC as the communication protocol among the microservices. I realised that I have to copy and paste the proto files to all microservices. Futhermore, if there is a change in definition, I will have to C&P again to all relevant microservices.

How should the proto files be shared? Preferably there is a common that we can call to upload and download the updated proto files.

Comment: you can keep that service as a dependency during build time in maven or Gradle, so that each time build runs, it fetches the latest Jar against that repo. This will just force you to rebuild Proto service and the impact can be seen in services implementing it's stubs

Comment: Not a direct answer, but make sure to follow best practices for backward compatibility when sharing protos between projects.  Mainly: do not re-use field numbers or remove support for services/methods/messages/fields without changing the package path (which typically should include the major version number in it).